# Count data and binomial distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, binomial-distribution

My problem described in buckets and balls (this is stats after all)...

I have 1 million buckets.
In each bucket I have some number of balls.

I want to model this system so that I have the expected number of balls for a bucket. (I expect my distrubtion of balls per bucket to be "gaussian" shaped)

Since my counts are integers I'm immediately pointed to the binomial distribution.   However, I can't seem to wrap my head around the notion of successes and failures in my system since every observation is a success.

Can anyone point out the vital piece of information that would help me figure out what distribution to use?

**Edit**:  I want to fit a distribution to my system to model the buckets and balls because these represent the noise in another problem.  If I can parameterize this distribution (i.e., if it is binomial),   then I can use that to pull my signal from the noise in another problem.

Comment: So far, there is nothing about stats (or probability for that matter) in your question, because nothing is happening!  What exactly are you *doing* with all these buckets and balls?

Comment: I think @whuber's question is, where is the randomness?  For example, is there a known total number of balls that get randomly allocated to buckets?  Or an unknown total number? Or do the buckets somehow generate balls themselves through an internal process?

Comment: @PeterEllis Thanks for the clarification.   Think of this as a coverage problem.  So we throw some extremely large (though unknown) number of balls and some number end up in each bucket.  There are way too many buckets and balls to look at in practice, so I pull out say 1000 buckets, and want to determine the best way to paramaterize the distribution of number of balls per bucket.

Comment: If you are throwing $n$ balls into $10^6$ bins where each bin is equally likely then the number of balls that end up going into a specific bin has a $\text{Binomial}(n,10^{-6})$ distribution.  This can be approximated by a $\text{Poisson}(n/10^6)$ distribution, extremely well approximated if you are throwing millions of balls.

Comment: Great!   I don't suppose you can point me to a link that explains how the binomial (used to model success / failure rates) can explain numbers of balls randomly landing in bins?  ie.   per bin I don't have a number of trials with success or failure,   I just have a count.

Comment: From an individual bucket's perspective think of $n$ trials where it has a $10^{-6}$ probability of successfully receiving the ball.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for parametric distributions that are defined on non-negative integer values with no clear-cut upper limit, then consider the Poisson and the negative binomial distributions. They do have probabilistic interpretations, but it would be irrelevant for you. But the commenters are right: if you know anything at all about the process generating the noise distribution (eg how do you know they are non-negative integers?), you can probably find models that are actually meaningful for your case.